# How to update (in memory) the value of IConfigurationSection

Tags: asp.net-core

Given that `Config` is an `IConfiguration` and `services` is an `ServiceCollection`, the code below:

```
        var section = Config.GetSection("MyDatabaseOptions");
        var configdb = secao.Get<MyDbConfiguration>();
        configdb.ConnectionString = DoSomethingWithSectionObject(configdb);
```

I would like to update `section` with the new content of `configdb.ConnectionString` to be able to configure it on `ServiceCollection` using:

```
services.Configure<MyDbConfiguration>(section);
```

How I could do it? Or there's another approach?

Comment: There's a tag for questions specifically on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration?

Comment: dit you try to add `AddInMemoryCollection` in your configuration and update the dictionary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IConfiguration` is just a hierarchy of strings with a path to it under the hood, so you can modify the value using the indexer with the correct key:

```
var section = Config.GetSection("MyDatabaseOptions");
var configdb = section.Get<MyDbConfiguration>();
section[nameof(MyDbConfiguration.ConnectionString)] = DoSomethingWithSectionObject(configdb);
```

But it applies only to strings, if you want to modify the whole structure it would be a bit more complicated, but the idea would still be the same - you need to specify the path to the property and string value, e.g.:

```
Configuration[$"{section.Path}:{nameof(MyDbConfiguration.ConnectionString)}"] = "new value";
```